# Typical workflow in measuring code coverage

Tags: code-coverage

I had a situation at work just arise that made me question my understanding of the workflow one executes in measuring code coverage across multiple test driver applications.

Is this workflow accurate...

1. Compile special build of application capable of measuring code coverage.
2. Run applications to generate code coverage result files.
3. Merge code coverage result files to measure the extent of code coverage from the suite of testing conducted for the code base (unit, integration, regression, etc).
4. Report overall results from the merged file.

It seems like folks are generating individual reports for each test application, which gives scattered figures for the coverage, some in this sub-report, some in this other sub-report, the overlap of which is ambiguous.

So my main confusion is around point 3 and how it relates to multiple test applications and the design of code coverage tools with respect to how contributions from various tests are pooled/merged.

Just for some perspective, I'm focusing on one language, one revision of a code base, and multiple test applications exercising that code base. And with respect to the "design of code coverage tools" I'm looking for the perspective of the developer who's generating the reports, not so much the internal details of result file formats and details regarding how the merge is implemented but rather a more conceptual step by step set of actions the developer conducts by virtue of the tools' UX design so to speak. I'd like to better understand the artifacts produced by code coverage tools and how they originate and ultimately fit together.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge coverage information if the tools don't agree on how to represent that information in a way that information can be collectively merged.

This means you pretty much can't combine coverage information from tools for multiple languages, because most of the test coverage tool vendors only make a tool for one language.

Its obviously easier to combine information produced by one tool for one langauge, and even easier to combine information from one tool for multiple test runs against a specific program instance.

You also have a problem if the application changes during the testing process.  You may have coverage information from the application as it was yesterday, and new information from today.  Can you safely merge this data?  Mostly not, because code changes can have arbitrary effect on the program function.   Really sophisticated program analysis would enable merging such coverage data; I've not seen any production test coverage tools that could do this.

(My company makes test coverage tools that handle all the cases above except across application changes... because that is really hard :).

Comment: That's a good distinction about multiple languages and the representation format. I'm however considering a single language, C++, and a bunch of google test executables basically. I'm also considering one snapshot of the codebase, not an evolving one. The merging is across distinct test applications of the same codebase at the same revision.
(btw Semantic Designs has some impressive tool sets. I still remember that catchy line "Can't be that hard...oops, what's a trigraph?")

Comment: Did you have a question about merging test coverage data from multiple tests applied to a single codebase?  In principle, this isn't hard.  Test coverage is really just a set of executed locations; merging is set union.  The tricky issues are "what do you mean by 'location'", how is the set represented [including what is a set element], and what do you have to say to the tool to cause the merge (or more complex comparison of test coverage sets) to occur?

Comment: Essentially yes, one question is how is test coverage data distributed exactly in this multiple test scenario, does each test application generate a distinct code coverage result file to the file system or does it connect to a single result file via a command line argument or something and pool into it? I used to run BullsEye tests some years ago but forgot these details. I think the team here is using some feature in Visual Studio somehow.

Comment: You are asking "where are the sets stored, and how does a merge take place?"   Our tools store sets from test runs in date-stamped files, and the test coverage display tool can merge sets of such files (thousands at once if you want).   You could keep one canonical set in a disk file, and update that file after each run (and in fact, our PHP version does that to handle test coverage collected from each accessed web page).   I prefer the separate files because then you can combine them in arbitrary ways; for instance it is useful to *subtract* one set from another  ...

Comment: ...  to find out what one test actually tests, compared to what another test actually tests.    If you insist on merging sets after each run, the only combination you can get is merge-everything.